# How to resize text when box reaches a certain width

Tags: css

I have data coming in from the database. I would like to resize the text of the width box so it doesn't drop to the line below it. However, I only want to resize the text when it reaches a certain width. The data will vary and therefore the width of the text box will vary, and there are multiple records that are shown on the screen. I want the text to stay the same, but only the ones that have a larger width, I would like to resize. The other text, I would like to keep the same. I looked online but I couldn't find anything that could help this particular situation.

Comment: I don't think this is possible in pure css, you'll probably have to use javascript.

Comment: That's right, there is no `max-font-size` property, so what you need to do is use JavaScript to measure the width of the text and reduce the font size until it fits. There are probably libraries that do this.

Comment: You could do this with SASS LESS variables, and even with CSSINJS techniques. Otherwise javascript will be your friend. There are plugins like bigtext if you use jQuery or fitty like the sir answered.

Comment: thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out >> https://css-tricks.com/fitting-text-to-a-container/

```js
fitty('h1');
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bowlby+One+SC');

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Bowlby One SC', cursive;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/fitty.min.js"></script>
<h1>Fit Me</h1>
```